# How to find all @viewport blocks in CSS

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to find all @viewport (including @-ms-viewport etc) blocks in a css file with a regexp:

```
/@.*?viewport.*?\}/ms
```

I expect results like:

```
@viewport { ... }
```

But this regexp returns the longest results, including part of css file from the first occurrence of `@` to `viewport` block, i. e.:

```
@media (min-width ... @viewport { ... }
```

I use lazy quantifier `*?` between `@` and `viewport`, but getting the biggest result. Where my mistake?

Comment: So the first `.*?` should not skip over white space. If so, use [`@\S*?viewport.*?\}`](https://regex101.com/r/DbHCIG/1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `.*?`, use `[^@]*` to match any character that is not `@`

```
/@[^@]*viewport.*?\}/ms
```

Comment: Thanks! Tried with more fierce variant `/@[a-zA-Z\-]*?viewport.*?\}/ms` - it works!

Answer (score 0):

Here, we would start with a simple expression with a dash `-` boundary after `@`:

```
$re = '/@(-.+)?viewport.+?\}/ms';
$str = '@media (min-width ... @viewport { ... }@media (min-width ... @viewport { ... }

@media (min-width ... @viewport { ... }

@media (min-width ... @-ms-viewport { ... }';

preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER, 0);

// Print the entire match result
var_dump($matches);
```

#### [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/H8Vls6/1/)

Comment: It will fail with: `@-whatever-blah ... @media (min-width ... @viewport { ... }`